# Making sense of uses constraint violation

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, osgi, rcp

I'm trying to build an RCP application and I've been incrementally adding bundles and dependencies to fill it out more with desired functionality. When testing my product by launch, I get the following uses constraint violation and I'm unsure why or how this came to be. I have the following bundles in my product: `org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.win32`, `com.sun.jna.platform`, and `org.apache.http.client`.

Can someone help explain to me what is happening here and how I could possible go about addressing the problem?

```
  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.win32 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.win32"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.1.v20180628-1139"; singleton:="true"] because it is exposed to package 'com.sun.jna.platform.win32' from resources com.sun.jna.platform [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.sun.jna.platform"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.1.0.v20170410-1117"] and org.apache.http.client [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.apache.http.client"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.5.0.v20181221_2153"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.win32 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.win32"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.1.v20180628-1139"; singleton:="true"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.jna.platform.win32)(version>=4.1.0))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: com.sun.jna.platform.win32
  com.sun.jna.platform [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.sun.jna.platform"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.1.0.v20170410-1117"]

Chain 2:
  org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.win32 [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.win32"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.7.1.v20180628-1139"; singleton:="true"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http.impl.auth.win)(version>=4.3.6))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.apache.http.impl.auth.win; uses:=com.sun.jna.platform.win32
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.jna.platform.win32
  org.apache.http.client [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.apache.http.client"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.5.0.v20181221_2153"]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1682)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1555)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62956624/java-lang-linkageerror-loader-constraint-violation-loader/62969115#62969115

Comment: Eclipse has done a horrible job with packages. Importing packages in an Eclipse RCP app is a mess. Requiring bundles, as the alternative, is even more of a mess. In Bndtools, we actually import package with bundle-symbolic-name and bundle-version attributes to get the packages from the proper exporter. https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/pull/2867/commits/ba6e0e540b22f0be0c89c9c8a8414b471505710b#diff-214fea0d34c16a4b0043ee22d0099bff

Comment: @BJHargrave How is your comment related to the question where the _uses constraint violation_ is caused by having this combination of some third-party bundles, not by something in the source code (or did I misunderstand the error message and Peter Kriens)? Could you please be more precise and more professional by avoiding terms like _mess_ and _horrible_.